# Node.js and JSON: retreiving info from external website api

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

This code does not work because it cannot read an address to an external website

Needed the "result" value from that json file.

Is there a simple fix to this possibly to be able to read a json from an external website?

Even better, if your willing to help more, I wanted it to rescan that website every 5 minutes (or you can set any time)

Thank you!

```
    const fs = require("fs");
    fs.readFile("", "utf8", (err, jsonString) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error reading json", err);
        return;
      }
      try {
        const useroutput = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        console.log("Customer address is:", useroutput.result); 
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error parsing JSON string:", err);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you don't mind adding a dependency, how about using [node-fetch?](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HTTPS](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) module is what you're looking for, although there are many libraries that can make these calls easier.

```js
const https = require('https');

const url = ''; // https://...
https.get(url, res => {
  // capture the response buffers
  const chunks = [];
  res.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
  res.on('end', () => {
    const jsonString = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf-8');
    // Handle as you will, JSON.parse(), etc.
  });
}).on('error', error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

setInterval is what you need. Copying example provided by @lucasvw

```
const https = require('https');
const url = ''; // https://...
setInterval(()=>{
https.get(url, res => {
    // capture the response buffers
    const chunks = [];
    res.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
    res.on('end', () => {
    const jsonString = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf-8');
    // Handle as you will, JSON.parse(), etc.
    });
}).on('error', error => {
    console.log(error);
});
},300000);
```